# How to fill na in pandas by the mode of a group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fillna

I have a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
  df = 

       a                    b
       a1                   b1
       a1                   b2
       a1                   b1
       a1                   Nan
       a2                   b1
       a2                   b2
       a2                   b2
       a2                   Nan
       a2                   b2
       a3                   Nan
```

For every value of `a`, `b` can have multiple values of `b` corresponding to it. I want to fill up all the `nan` values of `b` with the mode of `b` value grouped by the corresponding value of `a`.

The resulting dataframe should look like the following:

```
  df = 

       a                    b
       a1                   b1
       a1                   b2
       a1                   b1
       a1                   ***b1***
       a2                   b1
       a2                   b2
       a2                   b2
       a2                   **b2**
       a2                   b2
       a3                   b2
```

Above `b1` was the mode of `b` corresponding to `a1`. Similarly, `b2` was the mode corresponding to `a2`. Finally, a3 had no data, so it fills it by global mode `b2`.

For every nan value of column b, I want to fill it with the mode of the value of b column, but, for that particular value of a, whatever is the mode.

EDIT:

If there is a group `a` for which there is no data on `b`, then fill it by global mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
# lazy grouping
groups = df.groupby('a')

# where all the rows within a group is NaN
all_na = groups['b'].transform(lambda x: x.isna().all())

# fill global mode
df.loc[all_na, 'b'] = df['b'].mode()[0]

# fill with local mode
mode_by_group = groups['b'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(mod_by_group)
```

Comment: It works for the example, but, for my original data set, it is giving: `IndexError: index out of bounds` in the first line. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: You have a group `a` with no data on `b`

Comment: Do you know how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

`You are getting the IndexError: index out of bounds because last a column value a3` does not have corresponding b column value. Hence there is no group to fill. `Solution would be have try catch block while fillna and then apply ffill and bfill` . Here is the code solution.

```
data_stack = [['a1','b1'],['a1','b2'],['a1','b1'],['a1',np.nan],['a2','b1'], 
['a2','b2'],['a2','b2'],['a2',np.nan],['a2','b2'],['a3',np.nan]]
df_try_stack = pd.DataFrame(data_stack, columns=["a","b"])

# This function will fill na values of group to the mode value
def fillna_group(grp):
    try:
        return grp.fillna(grp.mode()[0])
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Error as no correspindg group: ' + str(e))
df_try_stack["b"] = df_try_stack["b"].fillna(df_try_stack.groupby(["a"]) 
['b'].transform(lambda grp : fillna_group(grp)))
df_try_stack = df_try_stack.ffill(axis = 0)
df_try_stack = df_try_stack.bfill(axis =0)
```